# 400. That’s an error. Error: invalid_request

Tags: google-signin

Google sign in authentication is working on my localhost . But not on the actual server, my server ip address is something like 54.*.*.* , here is the [Google auth details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yauKj.png)

I have added , both localhost and my server ip address in the authorized javascript origin fields, but it works only on localhost.

When i try to sign in with google on the server,It gives an error as invalid_request.

I'm new to this, so please some one help me get to rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not whitelisted your IP address on your Google Developer Console, you will have this problem.  The request MUST come from a whitelisted URL.

Solved my problem, try it out.